# Entry next sibling return a deactivated entry

Tags: entry, status

I got an entry template from a structured section.
With prev / next nav links at entry bottom.
But the next sibling is deactivated.
So the page return is 404 not found !

```
{% set prev = entry.prevSibling %}  
{% set next = entry.nextSibling %}

{% if prev %}
    <a class="nav-prev nav-left" href="{{ prev.url }}"><&nbsp;{{ prev.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% if next %}
    <a class="nav-next nav-right" href="{{ next.url }}">{{ next.title }}&nbsp;></a>
{% endif %}
```

Should it be `status=live` by default no?

Answer (score 7):

The [getNextSibling](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNextSibling) documentation says:

> getNextSibling() will return the next sibling whether or not it’s enabled. If you want to get the closest enabled sibling, you can do this instead:

```
{% set next = craft.entries.positionedAfter(entry).order('lft asc').first() %}
```

Similarly for [getPrevSibling](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getPrevSibling) to get the previous enabled sibling you can do:

```
{% set prev = craft.entries.positionedBefore(entry).order('lft desc').first() %}
```

Comment: This 'getNextSibling' thing is something I've stumbled over a couple time. Thanks for the post Marion.

Comment: I'd suggest adding ".siblingOf(entry)" into those suggestions so you only get siblings. Otherwise this answer gives you the next entry regardless of hierarchy :)

Answer (score 5):

Just an updated version of Marion's answer for Craft CMS 3 since `order` and `first` are deprecated.

```
{% set prev = craft.entries.positionedBefore(entry).orderBy('lft desc').one() %}

{% set next = craft.entries.positionedAfter(entry).orderBy('lft asc').one() %}
```